# How to transform roots/weights from the simple root basis to the H-basis?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

- Often the roots and weights of some Lie algebra are written in terms of the **simple root basis** $$ r =(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)=a_1 \alpha_1 + a_2 \alpha_2 + a_3 \alpha_3 +\ldots,$$ where $α_i$ denotes the simple roots.
- For many applications more useful is the **fundamental weight basis**,
  $$ w =(b_1,b_2,b_3,\ldots)=b_1 \omega_1 + b_2  \omega_2 + b_3  \omega_3 +\ldots,$$ where $\omega_i$ denotes the fundamental weights.

We can change between these two bases using the Cartan matrix and its inverse.

There is a third basis called **H-basis**, where we write each weight or root in terms of the eigenvalue of the Cartan generators $H_i$, when they act on them:

$$ H_i r = \lambda_i r \rightarrow r=( \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \ldots ) $$

***Given a set of weights/roots in the simple root basis, how can I compute the coefficents in the Cartan-Weyl basis? In other words, how can we change from the simple root to the Cartan-Weyl basis?***